# Android ListView Scrollable

Tags: android

Is there a way to determine if a list view needs to scroll to display all of its contents?

In other words, are the combined heights of all the children greater than the height of the list view itself.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried using it this way, but in principle [if `getLastVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29) equals `getCount()-1`, all items should be visible. It's possible that there is still a bit of scrolling needed, less than the height of a row, and I don't know if that matters in your case or not.

If it does, you could always iterate over the visible children and sum their heights.

Comment: I've tried it this way once.and found out, that it still delivers `no scrolling` when about half of the last item is scrolled out. I ended up with your second way but also adding up the separators between the items.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some ways a while ago and ended with simply calculating and comparing the height of the list view with the sum of the heights of all items and the sum of all separators.